# How to make a package the prefered conflict winner all together in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I know that the package `conflicted` let's us specify which function to use as default by using `conflict_prefer()`. But i want to make all functions from `tidyverse` the prefered ones. Is there a single line solution for this?

Comment: You are looking for `help("conflicted_prefer_all")`.

Comment: Btw. the package's name is `conflicted`.

Comment: Honestly, the *real* solution is not to rely on bloat-inducing packages like ‘tidyverse’ and, on the contrary, being judicious about which packages and which names to attach. `library(tidyverse)` is in direct contradiction to established software engineering best practices; its use should therefore be discouraged (except in very limited cases, and pretty much only for five-line throwaway scripts).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I use it for my reports only. I would not use it for anything production ready.
@Roland using `conflicted_prefer_all` weirdly takes a lot longer. It's not only for the current conflicts but all package functions combined i assume.

Comment: @Rootsyl Well, if that's an issue for you, you should rely on better practices. As Konrad pointed out, don't use the tidyverse package (I refuse to even install it). And use `::` to explicitly refer to a function from a specific namespace if you have namespace conflicts.